# Parsing YAML file using Perl

Tags: perl, yaml

I need some help in parsing the following config.yml file:

```
yamlFile:    
    map:    
        "[abcd.txt]":    
            - name: John    
            - city: Omaha    
        "[efgh.txt]":    
            - name: Sandra    
            - city: Columbus    
        "[ijkl.txt]":    
            - name: Annie   
            - city: Chicago
```

I am using the following script to parse.

```perl
my $config = LoadFile('config.yml');   
use Data::Dumper;    

for my $conf ( keys %$config ) {    
    print "$conf\n";   
    my $map = $config->{$conf};    
    for my $map1 ( keys %$map ) {    
        print "$map1\n";    
    }    
}
```

This prints the following:

```
yamlFile    
map
```

Since the keys of $map1 are different, how do I proceed further to get the name and city of each element?

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: I am using Tiny

Comment: I can't reproduce your output, I'm getting `map\n[abcd.txt]\n[efgh.txt]\n[ijkl.txt]` back.

Comment: The beginning of the yaml file is as below. Looks like yamlFile: was missed at the top

Comment: Please, update the question instead of describing the fixes in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to access the items in the YAML config file:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw(LoadFile);

my $config = LoadFile('config.yml');   
my $map_hash = $config->{yamlFile}{map};    
for my $conf ( keys %$map_hash ) {    
    say $conf;   
    my $elems = $map_hash->{$conf};
    for my $map1 ( @$elems ) {    
        for my $data ( keys %$map1 ) {
            say "$data:", $map1->{$data};
        }
    }    
}
```

**Output**:

```
[ijkl.txt]
name:Annie
city:Chicago
[abcd.txt]
name:John
city:Omaha
[efgh.txt]
name:Sandra
city:Columbus
```

Comment: Can't use string ("ijkl.txt") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: My guess is that it is this statement: `my $elems = $map_hash->{$conf}` that gives the error. Can you check if that is correct?

Comment: The error is occurring at:  for my $data ( keys %$map1 )

Comment: Then `$map1` is most likely not a hash reference. We have to find out why. So then we check the contents of `$elems` two lines above. It should be an array ref of two elements, each a hash reference. But according to what you say, it seems like it has become an array ref of strings instead. Please check if that is the case.